# How to test view helpers with database access

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I've got some view helpers (crossmodule), which need access to the database. A common example for this could be a `NotificationHelper`, which prints out a users notifications across many pages:

```
<div class="notifications">
<?php echo $this->notifications()->render(); ?>
</div>
```

While this is very handy, it seems very hard to do smokescreen testing / unit testing on controllers using `AbstractHttpControllerTestCase`, because the Helper would always want to access the database (which he obviously shouldn't, should he?). So in order to prevent this, I would need to mock the `NotificationHelper`. But that isn't enough, because a mock would return for `$this->notifications()`: `null`, and `render()` would therefore fail.

The only methods I can come up with, is to:

- Mock all dependencies of `NotificationHelper`
- Define return values of `NotificationHelper`, like (in this case) `__invoke()`
- Detach the RendererListener, but this would cause that views wouldn't get tested in any way (it's sometimes usefull to see, if e.g. all `<? echo $this->url('route'); ?>` still work.

The first two methods seem very bloated and somehow wrong, as I would need to do this with every Helper in every ControllerTest.

The third method takes away some comfort, because view templates wouldn't get tested any more.

Is there a better way of doing this? Or is the whole process wrong? Or did I get the idea completly wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AbstractHttpControllerTestCase` can be used for functional testing, but is not supposed to help with real unit tests.